# Verifying a UAE visa

Tags: visas, legal, uae, pakistani-citizens

I am from Islamabad, Pakistan. My brother got a work visa for UAE via a travel agent who's not trustable. So I want to verify that the visa is real. How can I do that? Or can anyone done it for me?

[image]

Comment: The name and passport number should be redacted.

Comment: Thanks @GayotFow, But what about my question..???

Comment: No clue. Except to say that travel agents in south Asia are a known and widely condemned source of visa fraud.

Comment: It seems like a fake permit, check this page: http://ednrd.ae/portal/pls/portal/INIMM_DB.DBPK_VISAVALIDITY.Query_VisaValidity
the number of the permit does not match the allowed format in the official validity check page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have doubts as to the legitimacy of this document. Comparing it with a visa I recently had issued for someone from Pakistan, I find the following issues:

1. The actual visa copy has a watermark; which is visible even if you print and scan it.
2. There is a stamp on the bottom right.
3. The Expo 2020 stamp is on the bottom left.
4. The visa includes a page of instructions.
5. The visa number is written `unique number / year / sequence` (at least on this version).

Further, "e-visas" are reserved for short stay only. I believe the normal visa for permanent workers/residency are different.

However, please please please understand that I am not an official at the UAE ministry of foreign affairs; I am only comparing it with another e-visa that I had issued.

The best way to assure its legitimacy is to do any one of the following:

1. Call the UAE embassy in Karachi
2. Call the EDNRD Hotline +97143139999
3. Have the sponsor validate it online at the EDNRD website.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the result of some Googling. I am not an UAE official. But I have been unable to find anything at all which would indicate work permits exist as eVisas.

This [Google Image search](https://goo.gl/6paBAh) shows a traditional piece of paper with very visible anti forgery elements like the colorful (probably even hologram) round thingie on the bottom centre.

Forum posts talking about work permits usually mention a "pink slip" which corroborates with the image result.

Comment: That should be "a UAE official."

Comment: I am [curious](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296019/why-a-uae-offical-and-not-an-uae-official) why.

Comment: Because "UAE" is pronounced "yoo-ay-ee", which begins with a consonant sound. Likewise, "an SE question" ("ess-ee") but "a Stack Exchange question."